# Android Emulator InetAddress giving abnormal/incorrect IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been using below code to get local IP address of my phone and it is working perfect on real android device

```
  public String getIpAddress() {
    String ip = "";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces();
        while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                    .nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                    .getInetAddresses();
            while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();

                if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                    ip += "SiteLocalAddress: "
                            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
    }

    return ip;
}
```

But when I run same app having the above code in android emulator, it gives up abnormal IP address like this fec0::5504:ff:fe12:3456%210.0.2.15

Is there any configuration in android emulator that I should do to get correct IP address using above code? Or what can I do to get actual IP address?

Comment: Ipv 4 and Ipv 6.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: I did not invent ipv4. And i did not invent ipv6.

Comment: The code is returning the IPv6 form of IP address. IPv6 is the newer form of IP addresses as IPv4 will soon run out. You seem to be receiving the IPv6 address of your emulator.